# Magento 2 SSL Centos Varnish + How to update Magento 2 Shop without harming Main Page

Tags: magento2, ssl, varnish, backup, centos

Got two Questions actually sorry for that.

1. > I got varnish, when I turn the https:// SSL on, it goes super slow because varnish is not build for SSL, you can fix this by SSL
   >   termination, but no where you can find how to do this for centos 7,
   >   apache or nginx, simple explained

**Somebody can help?**
Because customers of course like SSL, but so slow, I put SSL off for now

2. > Thereby what is the way to develop magento 2 shop in an different directory, so the main magento 2 shop in my case:
   >   www.takoda.shop stay
   >   always online

What I mean here is when I develop the shop often it is out of the air in maintenance or something like that, or when I compile, it's also out of the air, of course killing for customers, maybe never coming back

So I want a backup directory or something like that where I can develop and edit the magento 2 shop without harming the front shop, when everything works perfectly, than I update this shop to the main shop.

**You got what I mean, or must i explain it more clearer?**

*I respect all the people who really care about helping and are much smarter and better than me in this parts!*

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

For your **first** question

In general you would do it like this:
1. Nginx (or other web server) for SSL termination
2. Varnish
3 Nginx (or other web server) to serve pages

For your **second** question

Once you have Varnish up, and you are doing a deployment many of the pages will be served from Varnish while you are doing a deployment. More robust solutions tend to be complex using blue/green deployments or build areas where you do all of the building (as you noted) and then copy over the generation and pub/static files.